# PrimeFaces: pass parameter <p:commondbutton actionListener/> in weblogic

Tags: primefaces, jsp-tags

I would like to know how to pass parameter in weblogic?

This is not support and get error of
5:03:39,735 ERROR JSFExceptionHandler [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] :121 - j_id1->"Encountered "(" at line 1, column 28.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "*" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "?" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...
    "
com.sun.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 28.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "*" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "?" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...

```
at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.generateParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.jj_consume_token(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.DeferredExpression(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.CompositeExpression(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createMethodExpression(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createMethodExpression(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getMethodExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:219)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ActionSourceRule$ActionListenerMapper2.applyMetadata(ActionSourceRule.java:133)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:77)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:125)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:96)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:345)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:162)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:162)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:162)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:392)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:363)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:104)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:162)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:114)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:156)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:94)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:79)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:363)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:342)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:196)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:151)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:89)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:79)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:148)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:734)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:96)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

Comment: show your jsf page relevant code

Comment: @Daniel <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{userMainAction.listAcsCountryEBean}" id="tblUserList">
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{userMainAction.doEditUser}" /><p:column headerText="#{message.label_userlist_country}"><h:outputText value="#{item.usrAcsCtryCd}" /></p:column><p:column headerText="#{message.label_userlist_UTCOffset}"><h:outputText value="#{item.usrAcsUtcTime}"/></p:column><p:columnheaderText="Edit"><p:commandButton id="cmduserEdit" icon="ui-icon" actionListner="#{userMainAction.doEditUser(item)}"/><p:rowEditor /></p:dataTable>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code have some weird chars... (you can see this if you copy paste it into notepad++ for example)

Try this one:

```
<p:dataTable var="item" value="#{userMainAction.listAcsCountryEBean}" id="tblUserList"> 
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{userMainAction.doEditUser}" />
    <p:column headerText="#{message.label_userlist_country}">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.usrAcsCtryCd}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{message.label_userlist_UTCOffset}">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.usrAcsUtcTime}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Edit">
        <p:commandButton id="cmduserEdit" icon="ui-icon" actionListner="#{userMainAction.doEditUser(item)}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:rowEditor />
</p:dataTable>
```